# nodejs request-promise url location not showing in headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-request, request-promise

I'm currently using request-promise in nodejs to make a request to a website and then return the headers, as I'm trying to get the url (location) of the request incase of redirects. Although the issue I'm having is that the location is not showing up in the headers when I'm logging them after the request.

My code:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36';
const url = //url

var _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
    return {'headers': response.headers, 'data': body};
  };

const options = {
    uri: url,
    followAllRedirects: true,
    method: 'get',
    gzip: true,
    transform: _include_headers,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': userAgent
    },
};

const p1 = rp(options).then((response, error, html) => {

    console.log(response.headers);

})
```

The console logs the headers, but it doesn't show the location in the headers object. Is there anyway I can find the location of the url after making the request and returning the headers?

Comment: You're passing `followAllRedirects: true` and the default for `followRedirect` is true.  That means that you're telling the `request()` library to HIDE the redirects from you by just following them and giving you only the final result after redirect.  If you want to get the redirect status and URL yourself, then you have to tell the `request()` library NOT to follow the redirects automatically so it will return the 3xx status and headers to you.

Answer (score 3):

What is your `request-promise` version?
You can try this snippet.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

    rp({
        uri: 'http://google.com',
        method: 'GET',
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.dir(response.headers);
        });
```

Comment: perfect, working for me I was not using `resolveWithFullResponse: true`

Answer (score 3):

When you set `followAllRedirects` to `true`, you won't have a `location` field in your response headers, and the only way to access the final redirected URL is to access the `response.request.uri` object that contains the final URL in its `href` property.

To do so, you can modify your `transform` function to pass an additional `finalUrl` property that is equal to `response.request.uri.href`:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36';
const url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

const _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
    return {
        'headers': response.headers, 
        'data': body, 
        'finalUrl': response.request.uri.href // contains final URL
    };
};

const options = {
    uri: url,
    followAllRedirects: true,
    method: 'get',
    gzip: true,
    transform: _include_headers,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': userAgent
    },
};

const p1 = rp(options).then((response, error, html) => {

    console.log(response.finalUrl);
});
```

In the example above, `http://www.stackoverflow.com` is redirected to `https://stackoverflow.com`, which is what the program prints.